# redirecting back to the app in paytm integration in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback, paytm, callbackurl

I am trying to integrate paytm in react native. but the problem is when I tap on pay button (call call_api) but then processing screen is coming and suddenly app navigate to current screen where I define pay button. please help here is my code

```
call_api = () => {
    fetch("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify([
        {
          mobile_no: "XXXXXx",
          user_id: "XX",
          patient_name: "XXXx",
        },
      ]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())

      .then((response) => {
        console.log("this checksum api esponse" + JSON.stringify(response));

        this.setState({ order_id: response[0].data.order_id });
        this.setState({ checksum: response[0].data.checksumhash });

        this.pay();
      });
  };



  pay = () => {
    const details = {
      //mode: "Production", // 'Staging' or 'Production'
      mode: "Production",
      MID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail",
      WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING",
      CHANNEL_ID: "WAP",
      TXN_AMOUNT: "1", // String
      ORDER_ID: this.state.order_id, // String
      // EMAIL: email, // String
      // MOBILE_NO: mobile, // String
      CUST_ID: "CUSTOMER_1", // String
      CHECKSUMHASH: `${this.state.checksum}`, //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility
       CALLBACK_URL:
         "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=" +
         `${this.state.order_id}`,
     // CALLBACK_URL: `https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<${this.state.order_id}>`,
    };
    Paytm.startPayment(details);
    console.log(details);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have Paytm Staging app installed on your device. You can get the same from the link mentioned on Paytm Developer Portal